# Alertview with integer

Tags: ios, integer, uialertview

Hello to everyone i would like to place my thinking about an alertview. I am thinking to create an Uialertview which will prompt the user to input two integers. Then i would like to retrieve these two integers and put the one on a timer and the second in an sql statement. So if anyone can help on how to implement that i would apreciate it. Thank you all.

Here is my code until now

```
UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"info" message:@"Set time For The Game." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
    alertView.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
NSLog(@"Entered: %@", [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]);
    [alertView show];
```

Comment: Check: `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use delegate methods of UIAlterView.

First of all make "self a delegate" instead of nil.

```
UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"info" message:@"Set time For The Game." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
```

Than add this function to your class:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UITextField *field = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", field.text);
}
```

To be 100% correct add also in your header class information that you implement this protocol .

Comment: Thank you for your advice Grzegorz but can you explain me how to  make "self a delegate" instead of nil

Comment: Look at first block of code I pasted (it's modified version of your code). delegate:self instead of delelgate:nil

Comment: Ok Grzegorz it worked. Thank you very much now is that possible to place a second textfield on that alertview and pass the integer variable in an sql statement?

Comment: Of course you can use [ intValue ] method on the text and pass it to SQL using [NSString stringWIthFormat:@"%d", value]; For second textfield the only option is to use UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput - but it's encrypted then. If you need something else you need to create your own popup class.

Comment: Can you explain me how to set the [intValue]?

Comment: int fieldIntValue = [field.text intValue]

Answer (score 0):

// Try this

```
UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"info" message:@"Set time For The Game." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
alertView.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
[alertView show];


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   NSLog(@"Entered: %@", [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]text]);
}
```